# How do I use Groovy's @Builder to also copy a POGO?

Tags: groovy, copy-constructor, builder

Groovy's `@Builder` annotation essentially adds the builder pattern to a class, typically a POGO.  What I'm looking to do is something akin to the following and I think it's akin to a copy constructor.

Given an existing instance of class `Foo`, `foo`, I'd like to do:

```
Foo copy = Foo.builder(foo).methodOne(...).methodTwo(...)...build()
```

That is, be able to pass in the instance `foo` to the `builder()` but that's not part of the (current) API.  I think if there were a way to convert a POGO to a `Map` there's a way to construct a POGO - but clearly not as clean.

Having a solution like this would also allow the user to work around `@Immutable` classes by constructing new ones from existing data without having to manually map each property.

Does anyone have an idea on how I might accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**  I've since learned that @Immutable makes all fields private and thus one cannot use `@Immutable` with `@Builder` so a solution for this becomes a lot more tricky if one wants to have immutable classes that follow a builder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Is a dedicated builder what you're looking for?

```
import groovy.transform.builder.*
import groovy.transform.*

 @ToString
 @Builder
 class Foo {
     String first, last
     int born

     Foo(){}

     @Builder(builderClassName='CopyBuilder', builderMethodName='copyBuilder')
     static Foo copy(Foo foo) {
         new Foo(first: foo.first, last: foo.last, born: foo.born)
     }
 }

def p = Foo.builder().first('Johnny').last('Depp').born(1963).build()
def c = Foo.copyBuilder().foo(p).build()
assert c != p
assert p.toString() == 'Foo(Johnny, Depp, 1963)'
assert c.toString() == 'Foo(Johnny, Depp, 1963)'
```

Comment: Yea, this is exactly what I want, but it would need to be generic.  I.e., I wouldn't want to have to specify all the properties to copy for every single model class since the entire point of the `@Builder` annotation is to add the builder pattern to the annotated class.  Seems like it would be fairly trivial to modify the corresponding `@Builder` AST class to overload the `builder()` method to take an instance of the same class and copy the properties over.  Maybe something with categories or meta class?  I'm still new so not sure this would be the right way to go.

Comment: I don't get it :/ Why don't you just use `clone` method? Also you need it to be generic when it comes to object type (want it work for multiple classes) or not specifying all the properties?

Comment: `clone()` only works on objects that implement the `Cloneable` interface which means that every model object would have to implement that interface.  This defeats the entire purpose of using Groovy which is to do more with less code.  Turns out, though, that this is a red herring because the `@Builder` requires that all fields are public (so Groovy can generate the setter methods).  This isn't a great solution because it means that now, all the data models lack integrity in the application.